# Rails - Validating an attribute based on another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have an Assignment class which belongs to both a User class and a Role class.  It stores three values - a reference to the User it belongs to, a reference to the Role it belongs to, and a string value indicating the name of the User who create the Assignment instance.

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role  

  attr_accessible :user, :role, :assigned_by_user

  ...
```

In my model validation, I would like to perform a check to make sure that the assigned_by_user attribute does match the name of a valid user.  However, I can't seem to access the User.find(...) method within the Assignment model.

How would I achieve this functionality?

Comment: sure you can! what's the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a "Check User" module to your lib folder (check_user.rb). Then in that file

```
 module CheckUser

 def search_user
  user = User.find_by_name(self.assigned_by_user)
  unless item.nil?
    errors.add(:name_found, "This username has already been taken")
  end
 end
```

Then in your Assignment model

```
 class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CheckUser
  validate :search_user
```

Comment: Oh, awesome, that worked much better than the hacky solution I put together last night.

Comment: As an extra note: Can also just add a similar method in your model and call it there rather than throw it in an entirely different file.