# Rails validation - validate parent model while creating child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have `ParentModel` that has_many `ChildModel`.

Is there a way to check (**validate**) `ParentModel` while creating a child (like for example check if a child record with the same name exists?

Comment: So it sounds like you might be looking for a composite unique index?  On a specific field and foreign key?

Comment: Would be OK if the validation should only check for name uniqueness, but it must be a little bit more complex, so I was thinking about defining a method and use it for validation

Comment: maybe this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849179/rails-validating-an-attribute-based-on-another-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple, please correct me if wrong.

```
def Parent 
    has_many :children 
end 
def Child
    belongs_to :parent
    #Here you could run some validations, for example:
    validates :name,presence: true, length: { minimum: 1 },uniqueness: { scope: :parent_id }
    #by running uniqueness with scope, you can repeat names, but not associated with the same parent. 
end
```

Then one could, for example:

```
p = Parent.first #suppose we already have the parent
p.child.new  #create a child, with attributes if needed 
p.valid? #p won't be valid unless his new child is
```

alternative:

```
p = Parent.first #suppose we already have the parent
c = Child.new  #create a child, with attributes if needed 
p.children << c #append the child to the collection, if C is invalid, then it won't be saved into the database
p.valid?   #validate,
```

Comment: Your solution is really simple. I ended up creating a custom method and accessing the parent of created (not yet saved) child with `self`